# ModelForm problem

Tags: django, django-forms

I have declared my model classes as found in [this link](http://pastebin.com/mVVh2h8k)....I now want to customize how my add/edit ModelForm for a `Vehicle` object is rendered in that I want the year, make, model, and manufacturer fields to be rendered separately as opposed to referring to the one `common_vehicle` field from the `Vehicle` class.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make Vehicle inherit CommonVehicle? (Depending on why you've got that FK there, of course -- you may really need it, but I'm guessing not)

Instead of:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    ...
    common_vehicle = models.ForeignKey(CommonVehicle)
```

Use:

```
class Vehicle(CommonVehicle):
    ...all your other Vehicle fields here, but not the FK to CommonVehicle
```